# Play all audio elements on a HTML page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

So I have a button that you can click to play every single audio element on the page, but they way it does it is not very good, it uses `getElementById` for every single element. My page has many audio elements and more are getting added, so I want to get this over with before this problem gets out of hand.

```js
document.getElementById("sound1").play();
document.getElementById("sound2").play();
document.getElementById("sound3").play();
document.getElementById("sound4").play();
document.getElementById("sound5").play();
document.getElementById("sound6").play();
// more code here: https://github.com/3kh0/3kh0.github.io/blob/main/projects/soundboard/index.html
```

I can use jQuery, but I am trying not to, so a plain JavaScript solution would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question of targeting all audio elements on a page, the following code will do that for you :

```
// create a HTMLCollection of audio elements in constant els
const els = document.getElementsByTagName("AUDIO");
// use Array.from() method to convert els to array,
//   then iterate over it
Array.from(els).forEach((el) => {
    el.play();
});
```

The same functionality could also be used to only play select groups of audio elements. One could use class names for this purpose, or data-attributes.

For example, all audio elements created like this ...

```
<audio controls class="group-one" data-group="one">
    <source src="file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

... could then be added to the HTMLCollection (in the case of `getElementsByClassName`) or NodeList (when using `querySelectorAll`) like this ...

```
const els = document.getElementsByClassName("group-one");    
// OR
const els = document.querySelectorAll('audio[data-group="one"]');
```